# Perl DBI - binding a list

Tags: sql, perl, dbi, bind-variables

How do I bind a variable to a SQL set for an IN query in Perl DBI?

Example:

```
my @nature = ('TYPE1','TYPE2'); # This is normally populated from elsewhere
my $qh = $dbh->prepare(
      "SELECT count(ref_no) FROM fm_fault WHERE nature IN ?"
) || die("Failed to prepare query: $DBI::errstr");

# Using the array here only takes the first entry in this example, using a array ref gives no result
# bind_param and named bind variables gives similar results
$qh->execute(@nature) || die("Failed to execute query: $DBI::errstr");

print $qh->fetchrow_array();
```

The result for the code as above results in only the count for `TYPE1`, while the required output is the sum of the count for `TYPE1` and `TYPE2`. Replacing the bind entry with a reference to `@nature` (`\@nature`), results in 0 results.

The main use-case for this is to allow a user to check multiple options using something like a checkbox group and it is to return all the results. A work-around is to construct a string to insert into the query - it works, however it needs a whole lot of filtering to avoid SQL injection issues and it is ugly...

In my case, the database is Oracle, ideally I want a generic solution that isn't affected by the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be as many `?` placeholders as there is elements in `@nature`, ie. `in (?,?,..)`

```
my @nature = ('TYPE1','TYPE2');
my $pholders = join ",", ("?") x @nature;
my $qh = $dbh->prepare(
    "SELECT count(ref_no) FROM fm_fault WHERE nature IN ($pholders)"
) or die("Failed to prepare query: $DBI::errstr");
```

Comment: Interesting approach... Doesn't work for named bind variables though... (I tried to simplify the example as much as possible, my full query has a few repeated variables where I'm using the Oracle style `:name` variables) (I wonder if you can mix `?` with the named type...) I'm still hoping there is a way to directly bind a set/list...

Comment: AFAIK, you have to use only named placeholders for Oracle.

Comment: That would be `my $pholders = join ", ", map ":$_",  1 .. @nature;`

Comment: Quick note: No, you can't mix placeholder styles... I'm using `:nat$_` currently..  Filling it in a loop with bind_param, but that can probably be done with `map`'s block form... (Edit: Map seems to make sense mainly when worried about the result, so one line for is probably the relevant option)

Comment: @Сухой27 - Nope, Oracle is perfectly happy with `?` placeholders.

Comment: @JimDavis I think this is only due `DBD::Oracle` [implementation](http://search.cpan.org/~pythian/DBD-Oracle-1.30/Oracle.pm#Placeholders)